# Eliminate queries with a temporary table that get update every x minutes

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a table with users

```
id | user_id | session_id | last_activity (datetime)
```

What is the best way to have a list of online users without to make a painful query on every user request? Lets say is it possible to have a cron every 1 minute and through this to create a temporary table with the distinct user_id that has last activity in the last minute? The main goal is to have something faster than this query

```
select user_id 
from users_session 
where last_activity > dateadd(mi, -1, Current_TimeStamp) 
group by user_id
```

Comment: Is the table indexed on `last_activity` descending?

Answer (score 2):

There are several things you could do, but I'd favour something like this:

At login (if you have a login?), insert a row into a table ActiveUsers. Every time a user does something, update the last_activity column in this table. Have a job that runs every minute, or two minutes, and deletes rows from this table where last_activity is `< DATEADD(mi, -10, GETDATE()`.

That way, your query to find active users is `SELECT user_id FROM ActiveUsers`.

Also, to get more information on active users, you do something like this:

```
SELECT U.name, U.age, U.shoe_size, U.is_premium_member, AU.last_activity
FROM Users U
JOIN ActiveUsers AU ON U.User_id = AU.User_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! Yes I have a login and i do almost the same thing here but because i use multiple active session per user i prefer to have the table above and to get informations from that table. Ok the query i provide its not complicated so is possible to have a second ActiveTable for this. But what happens when there is more complicated table? Is the option to have a separate temp table a good idea or not? And if yes do i have to lock the table every minute for the update!? thanks in advanced

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible to have a temporary table - were you thinking of something like a global temp (##)? You wouldn't have to explicitly lock it, SQL Server does that, but where you thinking of recreating the entire table every minute? Surely that is more intensive than my suggestion?

Comment: I dont know! :) You know better because my experience on this is very low. I defiantly want to have the above Sessions table up to date so I prefer to not have and another one table of online users. This option will need 2 queries on every user activity